# spring boot elastic search configuration without port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

How to configure elastic search with spring boot when you have dns URL of elastic search not port

@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackageClasses = { com.upgrad.careers.careersapi.repository.ElasticJobRepository.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { com.upgrad.careers.careersapi.service.ESService.class })
public class ElasticConfiguration {

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient client(){
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration =
            ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo("https://elastic_url")
            .withBasicAuth("username",
                    "password")
            .build();
    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate(){
    return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
}
```

}

I am getting this error

Cannot parse port number: https://elastic_url
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.InetSocketAddressParser.parse(InetSocketAddressParser.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfigurationBuilder.parse(ClientConfigurationBuilder.java:238)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfigurationBuilder.connectedTo(ClientConfigurationBuilder.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration$ClientConfigurationBuilderWithRequiredEndpoint.connectedTo(ClientConfiguration.java:189)
at com.upgrad.careers.careersapi.config.ElasticConfiguration.client(ElasticConfiguration.java:28)
at com.upgrad.careers.careersapi.config.ElasticConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c0c6635d.CGLIB$client$0()
at com.upgrad.careers.careersapi.config.ElasticConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c0c6635d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$90208c30.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
at com.upgrad.careers.careersapi.config.ElasticConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c0c6635d.client()
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
... 99 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53432', transport: 'socket'

Comment: You need to provide the elastic server host, not a URL. You've told it to connect to `https` with the port `//elastic_url`.

Comment: I have manage elastic search and elastic URL I am using same for querying through post man

Comment: Huh this is weird. Even if provide only host not url, it defaults to 9200 what is wrong from my point of view.

Comment: sorry, it's "host:port", like documented in the API docs for `connectedTo`. And for using SSL the port is 443.